# Computing Unemployment rates by education group from an indicator variable (Stata)

Tags: stata

I have the following variable indicating whether an observation is working or unemployed, where 0 indicates working and 1 refers to unemployed.

```
dataex unemp
input float unemp
0
0
0
0
1
.
1
```

When I tabulate the variable:

```
Unemploymen |
 t |              Freq.     
------------+--------------
 Employed   |    80      
 Unemployed |    20   
 Total LF        100
```

I essentially want to divide 20/100, to obtain a total unemployment variable of 20%. I have done this manually now, but think it is better to automate this as I also want to compute unemployment by different education groups and geographic regions.

```
gen unemployment_broad = .
replace unemployment_broad = (20/100)*100
```

The education variable is as follows, where 1 "Less than basic",
2 "Basic",
3 "Secondary",
4 "Higher education",

Is there a way to compute unemployment rate by each education group?

```
input float educ
2
4
4
4
2
4
1
3
3
3
```

Using Cybernike's solution, I tried to create a variable showing unemployment by education as follows, but I got an error:

```
gen unemp_educ = .
replace unemp_educ = bysort educ: summarize unemp
```

I essentially want to visualize unemployment by education. With something like this:

```
graph hbar (mean)  Unemployment, over(education)
```

This is because I also intend to replicate the same equation by demographic group, gender, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `unemployment` variable is coded as 0/1. Therefore, you can obtain the proportion unemployed by taking the mean value. You could do this using the `summarize` command, or using the `collapse` command. Both of these can be performed by `education` group.

```
clear
input unemp educ
0 2
0 4
0 4
0 4
1 2
0 3
1 3
1 1
1 3
end

bysort educ: summarize unemp

collapse (mean) unemp, by(educ)

list

     +-----------------+
     | educ      unemp |
     |-----------------|
  1. |    1          1 |
  2. |    2         .5 |
  3. |    3   .6666667 |
  4. |    4          0 |
     +-----------------+
```

In response to your edit, you can also save the mean values to the original dataset using:

```
bysort educ: egen unemp_mean = mean(unemp)
```

Your code for plotting the data seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks so much, the same code should work even if my gender variable is coded 1 & 2, correct? As in: ```bysort gender: summarize unemp_lfp
bysort gender: egen unemp_gender = mean(unemp_lfp)```?

Comment: Yes, the same code can also be applied to `gender` and should work regardless of the number of levels. The only thing to be careful for is that `unemp` is always coded as 0 and 1, as that's the only situation in which the trick for calculating proportions can work.

Comment: Suppose unemployed was coded 1 and employed 2; then `mean(unemp == 1)` would work too. The main twist is watching out for missing values.